# Update data in a table based on another table

Tags: sql-server

My question is relatively simple but I'm looking for the best way to do it.

There are 3 tables in my database: New_Training, Old_Training and Conversion. They are structured as follows:

```
New_Training

User_Nr    NewTraining_Nr
112233        10
223344        10
445566        11

Conversion

NewTraining_Nr   OldTraining_Nr
10                  8430
10                  8650
10                  8900
11                  9430
11                  9500

Old_Training (This is how it should look)

User_Nr   OldTraining_Nr   OldTrainingNr_Lvl
112233        8430               1
112233        8650               1
112233        8900               1
223344        8430               1
223344        8650               1
223344        8900               1
445566        9430               1
445566        9500               1
```

I would like to write a SQL script that checks the New_Training table to see if there's users and which NewTraining_Nr they have associated, convert the NewTraining_Nr to the OldTraining_nr by using the Conversion table and insert the value 1 into the OldTrainingNr_Lvl column for the corresponding OldTraining_Nr's for that user, updating the table.

In case the user is new (inside New_Training), the User_Nr along with the corresponding OldTraining_Nr and level 1 should be added to the Old_Training table.

This script should be dynamic in the sense that it shouldn't be dependent on the User_nr but instead loop through the User_Nr's inside the New_Training table.

Comment: Include what you have tried so far in your question.

Comment: You've tagged sql-server but written MySQL? Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to insert into your 3th table using a result from the first 2 tables, then this will do it

```
declare @New_Training table (User_Nr int, NewTraining_Nr int)
declare @Conversion table (NewTraining_Nr int, OldTraining_Nr int)
declare @Old_Training table (User_Nr int, OldTraining_Nr int, OldTrainingNr_Lvl int)

insert into @New_Training (User_Nr, NewTraining_Nr)
values (112233, 10), (223344, 10), (445566, 11)

insert into @Conversion (NewTraining_Nr, OldTraining_Nr)
values (10, 8430), (10, 8650), (10, 8900), (11, 9430), (11, 9500)

insert into @Old_Training (User_Nr, OldTraining_Nr, OldTrainingNr_Lvl)
select nt.User_Nr,
       c.OldTraining_Nr,
       1
from   @New_Training nt
  left join @Conversion c on nt.NewTraining_Nr = c.NewTraining_Nr

select * from @Old_Training
```

This will produce this result

```
User_Nr OldTraining_Nr  OldTrainingNr_Lvl   
------- --------------  -----------------   
112233      8430            1   
112233      8650            1   
112233      8900            1   
223344      8430            1   
223344      8650            1   
223344      8900            1   
445566      9430            1   
445566      9500            1
```

Comment: The only problem is that the Old_Training table needs to be updated with the data from the other 2 tables. How would you update an already existing table with the data from the select?

Comment: Not sure how you tag the answer's poster haha, @GuidoG

Comment: @StefanEsteban I updated my answer so it inserts the result into your 3th table

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into Old_Training (User_Nr, OldTraining_Nr, OldTrainingNr_Lvl)
select nt.User_Nr,
       c.OldTraining_Nr,
       1 as OldTrainingNr_Lvl
from New_Training nt
  left join Conversion c on nt.NewTraining_Nr = c.NewTraining_Nr
```

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for pointing the long term value of the answer. Keeping your suggestion in mind I will always focus the long term value of my answers. Thanks once again for reminding me and other people who see this comment about this important aspect while providing answers.